# Do multiple DbContext generate a deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Summarizing my code, I have a `IRepository<E>` that uses a `DbContextStrategy<E>`.

`DbContextStrategy<E>` extends from `DbContext` and uses a `DbSet<E>` for LINQ operations on the database.

`E` is just an entity type passed by generics.

In my Web API controller I am using this repository interface to fetch my resources.

However, some entities depend on other entities. And in `PUT` or `POST` requests for example, I should validate input foreign keys to check if they are valid.

As a result, I would need to instantiate a new `IRepository<X>` where `X` is the foreign entity type.

In order for me to make my development as easy as possible, I generated a layer of *base classes* that will handle configuration, cache, dependency injection and HTTP method binding for me.

In my least child controller I have the following method:

```
/// Base class provides me with the Season entity fetched from the database.
/// An IRepository<Season> is open in the background, and therefore, a DbContext too.
protected override Season UpdateEntity(Season entity, SeasonPostDTO dto)
{
     Task<bool> validatingShow = ValidateShow(dto.Show);

     entity.Number = dto.Number;
     entity.ReleaseDate = dto.ReleaseDate;
     entity.Image = dto.Image;
     entity.TVShowId = dto.Show;
     entity.BlameUserId = Convert.ToInt32(GetCurrentUserId());

     validatingShow.Wait();
     if (!validatingShow.Result)
          throw new EntityNotFoundException("Show not found");

     return entity;
}
```

This is the method that will handle the entity's update. The base controller will call it, and then call the `repository.Edit(entity)` which will update the entity in the `DbContext`. After the operation, the `IRepository<Season>` is disposed.

ValidateShow is a private method that just checks if a `showId` exists:

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateShow(int id) {

     //This will instantiate a new IRepository<TVShow>, and therefore a new DbContext
     return await UseAsyncDependency<TVShow, bool>(async (showRepo) => {

         return (await showRepo.ReadAsync(id)) != null;

     });
}
```

However, the `ValidateShow` method just stays in an infinite loop. I have debugged the method, and the call gets correctly delegated to the `DbSet<TVShow>` and the loop happens at: `context.Entities.FindAsync(keys)`.

The method works ok, because I used the same `ReadAsync` method to fetch the `Season` entity.

But it appears that it generates some kind of deadlock when there are two different `DbContext` open. (`DbSet<Season>` and `DbSet<TVShow>`)

I should note that both `DbContext` connects to the same database.

## Async / Await execution flow from IRepository to DbSet

`IRepository<E>` calls the `SelectAsync(keys)` method on an `IDao<E>`, which calls the `SelectAsync(keys)` method on `DbContextStrategy<E>`.

Here is the code trace:

**DefaultRepository : IRepository**:

```
public async Task<E> ReadAsync(params object[] keys) {
    if(keys == null || keys.Length < 1) return null;
    return await dao.SelectAsync(keys);
}
```

**DefaultDao : IDao**

```
public async Task<E> SelectAsync(params object[] keys) {
    return await ForEachStrategyAsync(async (strategy) => {
        return await strategy.SelectAsync(keys);
    }, (entity) => {
        return entity != null;
    });
}

private async Task<R> ForEachStrategyAsync<R>(Func<IPersistenceStrategy<E>, Task<R>> function,
                                              Func<R, bool> assertion) {

    R lastResult = default(R);
    foreach(IPersistenceStrategy<E> strategy in strategies) {
         lastResult = await function(strategy);
         if(assertion(lastResult)) break;
    }
    return lastResult;
}
```

**DbContextStrategy : IPersistenceStrategy**

```
public async Task<E> SelectAsync(params object[] keys) {
    return await context.Entities.FindAsync(keys);
}
```

Comment: why do you need all these async calls, It adds a level of code complexity and overhead but I don't see the benefit from it as you don't call HEAVY methods in parallel

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah What do you mean by `all these async calls`? I only showed one, and it's an I/O operation, which should be non-blocking

Comment: ValidateShow, ReadAsync and the action itself UpdateEntity is async (an async wrapper is created automatically by Framework). I would recommend to remove all custom async methods.

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah `UpdateEntity` is not async, but I confess it generates a new local task to call an async operation. But what do you expect me to do? I get better performance using the `async` methods provided by EntityFramework. I should then add `async` to the whole stack of function calls, otherwise the code won't compile at all.

Comment: Another observation, UseAsyncDependency mimics a ServiceLocator Pattern which is really not recommended (also called an anti pattern). A easy addition is to use some IoC framework (Autofac is my personal choice, but there many of them). This lets you inject the repo instance as a constuctor argument of the controller and use it in your action method to 'ValidateShow' by Id

Comment: Interesting, so how much is the performance gain of the async call?

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah Honestly, I have an even more abstract layer above `IRepository`, which is `IEntityManager`. The entity manager is being injected to the controller, but I want it to be hidden, therefore my base class defines the `UseAsyncDependency` to call that manager, and get its repository.

Comment: the UpdateEntity is definitly called in an async context managed by the asp.net framework (unless you took the effort to prevent it).

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah Take a look at: [Async Processing in EF6](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/async-processing.aspx) and [Managing DbContext the right way](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

Comment: I Found this quote on the article you posted:
In general, parallelizing database access within a single business transaction has little to no benefits and only adds significant complexity. Any parallel operation performed within the context of a business transaction should not access the database.

Comment: Could you please show a ReadAsync method implementation also?

Comment: @IbrahimbenSalah I'm not creating single business transactions, in base controllers, I'm also validating the authenticated user on a new thread (which also uses a DbContext), creating the cache headers, initializing the memcached if needed, an so forth. If that was all made synchronous then I would end up with a big blocking operation

Comment: @t3z `ReadAsync` ultimately ends up being `context.Entities.FindAsync(keys)`, where `context` is the `DbContext`, `Entities` is the `DbSet<E>`, and `keys` are the primary keys passed as arguments to the repository

Comment: It's clear, but show us _how_ do you handle _async part_ there.

Comment: @t3z Updated my question with the execution flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each instance of `DbContext` has its own transaction which might cause deadlock but you'd need a write operation for that to happen and DbContext only saves the changes to the database when you call `SaveChanges()` which you don't call before calling `validatingShow.Wait()`

It's much more likely that this `Wait()` call is a problem. If you're using async/await you should really use async/await for the whole call stack (`UpdateEntity()` and up including your Web API controller's methods)

The reason why this is happening is described here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: That is interesting. I'll try to modify my method call and do what you say. I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: I can't believe this was actually the issue. Thank you very much!!